# JQuery DataTables no me coje los datos

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Estoy usando **JQuery DataTables** para pintar unos datos en una Ventana Modal, pero, al querer obtener esos mismos datos al validar me da `undefined`, tampoco me deja insertar nuevas columnas, me las inserta como campos en blanco, adjunto el código:

## HTML

```
<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
    <table id="Propiedades" class="display projects-table table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Propiedad</th>
                <th>Valor</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

## JavaScript

Método ajax:

```
t = $('#Propiedades').DataTable({
                "language": {
                    "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/Spanish.json"
                },
                //Obtengo los datos correctamente
                "ajax": "/Configuracion/GetPropiedadesArtDataJson/" + $('#Id').val(),
                "bDestroy": true,
                "language": {
                    "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/Spanish.json"
                }, select: {
                    style: 'multi'
                },
                "iDisplayLength": 2,
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "Propiedad" },
                    { "data": "Valor" }
                ],
                "order": [[1, 'asc']],
                "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
                    runAllCharts();
                }
            });
```

**Click aceptar para calcular los datos:**

```
var data = t
            .rows()
            .data();

        propi = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            //Genero una string y concateno los datos para pasarselo al controlador, aquí es donde me sale undefined
            propi += data[i][0] + "{" + data[i][1] + "¬";
            console.log(propi);
            $('#Datos').val(propi);
        }
```

Probando en consola para ver en que lugar se me perdían los datos, comprobé que al entrar al bucle era donde *"desaparecían"* dejo unas capturas de la consola:

**Data:**

[image: data]

Propiedad y valor correctos

**String concatenado:**

[image: string concatenado]

¿por qué no me lo captura bien?

> Datos adicionales:

Al intentar insertar otra fila con `t.row.add([prop,val]).draw(false);` me genera las dos columnas con strings vacias `"",""`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Estás asumiendo que `data` es una matriz bidimensional, pero por lo que se ve en consola no es así, es un array de objetos del tipo

```
{
 Propiedad : ..., //string
 Valor: ..., //string
 Nombre: ...
}
```

Por lo que tendrías que acceder con `data[i].Propiedad` o `data[i].Valor` o `data[i].Nombre`